# How to use a global string in Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, global-variables

How to use a global string in Broadcast receiver? What is wrong with sms variable?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String sms=""; //here is wrong???
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null ,null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        if(cur.getString(13).startsWith("\n ")){
            sms +=cur.getString(13)+"\n";
        }             
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tabel);
    text.setText(sms);
    //here works well

    private final BroadcastReceiver SMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
              Object messages[]=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
              SmsMessage smsMessage[]=new SmsMessage[messages.length];
              for (int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                     smsMessage[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])messages[i]);
                 }

              if(smsMessage[0].getMessageBody().startsWith("\n ")){
                     sms +=smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(); 
                     //or here is wrong?
                }

          TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tabel);
          text.setText(sms);
```

I want to make a list with all SMS received and this list must be updated when i received a sms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is creating a class and put all static variables in it.

So for example,

```
class Values {
    static public Activity frontActivity = null;
    static public int currentStatus = Status.IDLE;
}
```

and access them like

```
Values.frontActivity = this;
Values.currentStatis = Status.ACTIVE;
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to import Status.IDLE please?
I used "class Values {
     static public Activity frontActivity = null;
     static public String sms= Status.IDLE;"        
and i have a error at Status.IDLE.

Comment: Status is just an example class. and Static.ACTIVE is also an example final data. As long as you can access Values.currentStatus, you got the point